# Update selected item in celltable columns

Tags: java, gwt

i want to get properties on celltable viewed each time i select one item from the tree, and refresh the celltable, so it will be shown with the data that was selected. I have this code:

```
void updateSList(int dID) {
    m.setWidth("100%");
    m.setAutoHeaderRefreshDisabled(true);
    final ListDataProvider<M> list=new ListDataProvider<M> ();
    SimplePager.Resources pager=GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class);
    simplePager=new SimplePager(TextLocation.CENTER, pager, false,0,true);


    final List<M> me=list.getList();
    final ListHandler<M> sort=new ListHandler<M>(me);
    m.addColumnSortHandler(sort);
    Column<Metric,String> thirdColumn=new Column<M,String>(new TextCell()) {

        @Override
        public String getValue(M object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return object.getName();
        }

    };
    Column<M,String> forthColumn=new Column<M,String>(new TextCell()) {

        @Override
        public String getValue(M object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return object.getLast();
        }

    };

    m.addColumn(thirdColumn,"Name");
    thirdColumn.setSortable(true);
    sort.setComparator(thirdColumn,new Comparator<M>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(M m1, M m2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return m1.getName().compareTo(m2.getName());
        }});

    m.addColumn(forthColumn,"Last");
    forthColumn.setSortable(true);
    sort.setComparator(forthColumn,new Comparator<M>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(M m1, Mm2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return m1.getLast().compareTo(m2.getLast());
        }});


    AsyncCallback<List<M>> callback = new AsyncCallback<List<M>>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final List<M> result) {

        list.addDataDisplay(m);

        for (final M mt : result) {

                me.add(mt);

            }
        m.setVisibleRangeAndClearData(new Range(0,10), true);
        simplePager.setDisplay(m);
        }

    };

    rpcService.getData(dID, callback);
```

bevor select the second item:

> col1 | col2 | col3

after select the second item:

> col1 | col2 | col3 | col1 | col2 | col3

if i select one item from the tree i can see properties of this item, but if i select the next item i get the columns shown repeated twice with the properties of this item, but i want to get this view as normally shown, and not with increasing columns. Could someone suggest me where i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create and add new columns every time when `updateSList` is called. You only need one line of code inside this method:

```
rpcService.getData(dID, callback);
```

All other code should be moved to another method, called once when you first initialize this view.

Comment: thank you, do you mean to move to onSuccess, or create quite other method outside updateSList, and put all code there?

Comment: You need to move everything, including AsyncCallback, out of `updateSList`. Move to it a widget or view which holds this CellTable.